# Syntax hightlighting of template toolkit files in Aptana/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, template-toolkit, aptana

Does anyone know how I can add syntax highlighting to Eclipse/Aptana for Template Toolkit files?

All I need is for [% ... %] to be a different colour.

Comment: I use emacs. It has template toolkit mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this plugin http://perleclipse.com/TTEditor/

Answer (score 0):

I made syntax highiting for jEdit and it goes with the editor now. but I was just wandering how to do it for Eclipse.
I just stumbled upon the [FAQ section](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_an_editor_for_my_own_language%3F) where it is explained.
If you are good with JAVA I will be happy to use it :). Otherwise I will try to do it, but a Java developer will do it better.